# Train a model on a custom dataset for question-answering tasks

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to train a DistilBERT model on a custom dataset for question-answering tasks. I'm using hugginface library. The issue that I'm encountering is that I get an empty answer even though the answer exists in my dataset. This is how my `data.json` file looks like(it has more than 100 questions-answers):

```
[
{
"question": "What is the capital of Japan?",
"answer": "Tokyo",
"context": "Japan is an island nation located in East Asia. Its capital is a bustling metropolis known for its technology, fashion, and cuisine."
},
{
"question": "Who painted the Mona Lisa?",
"answer": "Leonardo da Vinci",
"context": "The Mona Lisa is a famous portrait painting that is believed to have been created by an Italian artist and inventor known for his wide-ranging interests and talents."
},
...
]
```

I got the script to work when I provided a context for each question asked, but what I want to do is that I want it to be able to give an answer based on the question without the need for context. I tried giving a general context to work with but it didn't work as well. I tried increasing the epochs and adjusting the batch size and learning rate but cannot get it to work. This is what I have tried so far:

```
# pip install torch transformers

import json
import torch
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForQuestionAnswering, Trainer, TrainingArguments, PreTrainedModel, PreTrainedTokenizerFast, AdamW

# Load questions, answers, and contexts from the JSON file
with open('data.json', 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

questions = [item['question'] for item in data]
answers = [item['answer'] for item in data]
contexts = [item['context'] for item in data]

# Split the data into training and validation sets
split_index = int(0.8 * len(questions))
train_questions, val_questions = questions[:split_index], questions[split_index:]
train_answers, val_answers = answers[:split_index], answers[split_index:]
train_contexts, val_contexts = contexts[:split_index], contexts[split_index:]

# Choose a pre-trained model and tokenizer
model_name = 'distilbert-base-uncased-distilled-squad'
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = AutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained(model_name)

# Prepare the dataset using the tokenizer
train_encodings = tokenizer(train_contexts, train_questions, truncation=True, padding=True)
val_encodings = tokenizer(val_contexts, val_questions, truncation=True, padding=True)

# Add start_positions and end_positions to the dataset
def add_token_positions(encodings, answers):
    start_positions = []
    end_positions = []
    for i in range(len(answers)):
        # Get the answer tokens
        answer_tokens = tokenizer.encode(answers[i], add_special_tokens=False)
        
        # Find the first occurrence of the answer tokens in the encoded input
        for j in range(len(encodings.input_ids[i]) - len(answer_tokens) + 1):
            if encodings.input_ids[i][j:j + len(answer_tokens)] == answer_tokens:
                ans_start = j
                ans_end = j + len(answer_tokens) - 1
                break
        else:
            # If the answer is not found, set the start and end positions to 0
            ans_start = 0
            ans_end = 0

        start_positions.append(ans_start)
        end_positions.append(ans_end)

    encodings.update({'start_positions': start_positions, 'end_positions': end_positions})

add_token_positions(train_encodings, train_answers)
add_token_positions(val_encodings, val_answers)

# Create a custom dataset class
class QADataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, encodings):
        self.encodings = encodings

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return {key: torch.tensor(val[idx]) for key, val in self.encodings.items()}

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.encodings.input_ids)

train_dataset = QADataset(train_encodings)
val_dataset = QADataset(val_encodings)

# Set up training arguments and the Trainer
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir='./results',
    num_train_epochs=11,
    per_device_train_batch_size=32,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=32,
    logging_dir='./logs',
    learning_rate=1e-4, # Custom learning rate
)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=val_dataset,
    optimizers=(AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=1e-4), None), # Custom optimizer with the learning rate
)

# Fine-tune the model
trainer.train()

# Save the fine-tuned model
model.save_pretrained('./FineTunedModel')
tokenizer.save_pretrained('./FineTunedModel')

# Load the fine-tuned model and tokenizer
model = AutoModelForQuestionAnswering.from_pretrained('./FineTunedModel')
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('./FineTunedModel')

def get_answer(model: PreTrainedModel, tokenizer: PreTrainedTokenizerFast, question: str, context: str = None) -> str:
    if context is None:
        context = """
        I am a chatbot designed to answer questions about a range of topics. My knowledge includes general facts, and I have been trained on a dataset containing specific information.
        """

    inputs = tokenizer(question, context, return_tensors='pt', max_length=512, truncation=True)
    outputs = model(**inputs)

    start_scores, end_scores = outputs.start_logits, outputs.end_logits
    start_index = torch.argmax(start_scores)
    end_index = torch.argmax(end_scores)

    tokens = tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(inputs["input_ids"][0])
    answer_tokens = tokens[start_index:end_index + 1]
    answer_tokens = [token for token in answer_tokens if token not in tokenizer.all_special_tokens]
    answer = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_string(answer_tokens)

    return answer

question = "What is the capital of Japan?"
answer = get_answer(model, tokenizer, question)
print("Answer:", answer)
```

This is the console output

```
{'train_runtime': 84.5162, 'train_samples_per_second': 4.295, 'train_steps_per_second': 0.26, 'train_loss': 0.3025119738145308, 'epoch': 11.0}
100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 22/22 [01:24<00:00,  3.84s/it]
Answer:
```

Comment: Plot the training curve, e.g. https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/plot-loss-curve-with-trainer/9767/10